# Как отдельно распарсить два блока, у которых общий класс?

Tags: java, android, html, парсер, jsoup

Есть такой блок, который хранит один пост (постов на странице много). В этом HTML фрагменте храниться id поста, ссылка на него, дата, время и теги. Кроме этого есть еще контент сам, но он в другом месте и с ним проблем нету.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="/story/17375">
            #17375</a> —
            <a href="/story/17375">7 февраля 2016, 17:00</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right">
            <a href="/bytag/relations">отношения</a>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Так вот, как мне отдельно распарсить каждый элемент с помощью JSOUP? Единственное, что у меня вышло правильно - это получить теги:

```
Elements storiesTags = doc.select("[style=text-align:right]");
```

Я пробовал получить элементы через класс:

```
Elements storiesIds = doc.getElementsByClass("col-xs-6");
```

Но тогда парсятся теги тоже. Как мне сделать так, чтобы отдельно распарсить теги, а отдельно все остальное? Например, если у этого класса есть такой стиль, то пусть это будут теги, если нету вообще такого атрибута как стиль, то пусть это идет в остальное? И при возможности как мне это все остальное распарсить на id, ссылку на пост, дату и время?

Всю эту работу у меня выполняет метод `parseDocument(Document doc)`. Есть определенный цикл, который проходит все страницы на сайте, каждая из которых содержит некоторое количество постов и на каждой итерации цикла вызывается этот метод. В результате он парсит не один пост, а некоторое количество и потом выводит в список результаты. Метод парсит как нужно только содержимое поста и его теги (голоса не совсем правильно, но это уже другой вопрос). Вот сам метод:

```
        public void parseDocument(Document doc) {
        ArrayList<NewStory> newStoryArrayList = new ArrayList<NewStory>();

        Elements storiesIds = null; // doc.getElementsByClass("col-xs-6");
        Elements storiesUrls = null; // doc.select("a.col-xs-6");
        Elements storiesDateAndTime = null;
        Elements storiesTags = doc.select("[style=text-align:right]");
        Elements storiesContent = doc.select("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");
        Elements storiesVotes = doc.select("[style=text-align:center]");

        // Iterator<Element> storiesIdIterator = storiesIds.iterator();
        // Iterator<Element> storiesUrlIterator = storiesUrls.iterator();
        // Iterator<Element> storiesDateAndTimeIterator = storiesDateAndTime.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> storiesTagIterator = storiesTags.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> storiesContentIterator = storiesContent.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> storiesVoteIterator = storiesVotes.iterator();

        while (storiesTagIterator.hasNext() && storiesContentIterator.hasNext() && storiesVoteIterator.hasNext()) {
            newStoryArrayList.add(new NewStory(null, null, null, storiesTagIterator.next().text(), storiesContentIterator.next().text(), storiesVoteIterator.next().text()));
        }

        for (NewStory newStory : newStoryArrayList) {
            MainActivity.this.newStoryArrayList.add(newStory);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Псевдоселектор [`:not`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html):

```
div.row>div.col-xs-6:not([style])
```

Выбрать внутри `div` с классом `.row` такие `div` с классом `.col-xs-6`, у которых нет атрибута `style`.

Еще можно обойтись одним итератором, и просто в правильном порядке вызывать `.next()` дважды, но в вашем коде это может привести к неожиданным проблемам при изменении порядка параметров конструктора.

Comment: Это то, что мне было нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто пробегайте циклом по всем одинаковым элементам и (например) определяя есть ли у них стиль разделяйте их.

```
Elements storiesIds = doc.getElementsByClass("col-xs-6");
for(Element el: storiesIds)
{
    if(el.hasAttr("style") {...}
    else {...}
}
```

Comment: Если честно я немного не понял как это впихнуть в мою уже написанную реализацию, поэтому я добавил свой метод...

Comment: @Kostya, теперь я не понимаю в чём ваша конкретная проблема.

Comment: Я бы хотел выделить парсером каждый элемент одной строчкой, как например для тегов:
Elements storiesTags = doc.select("[style=text-align:right]");

Хочу также сделать для других элементов, этот кусок работает неправильно и захватывает теги, так как они относятся к этому классу тоже:
Elements storiesIds = doc.getElementsByClass("col-xs-6");

Я хочу сделать что-то вроде такого средствами JSOUP, но не знаю как:
Elements storiesIds = doc.getElementsByClass("col-xs-6").notContain("style"); // и тогда теги не будут сюда попадать

Надеюсь Вы меня поняли :)